# IntelliJ Gradle deletes its own modules unexpectedly

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

This is the dialog indicating the modules which are being deleted

[image]

but when I import a new project with build.gradle and I do not enable `auto import` now I have a dialog asking my if I would like to enable `auto import`, and the modules are no longer deleted automatically.

[image]

Here is the `build.gradle` file

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle latest file.

Build command:
./gradlew deploy

Create Javadocs at ./latest/docs/javadoc/index.html
./gradlew buildJavadocs

Other commands of interest:
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 4.7
./gradlew tasks
./gradlew properties

Manual search for dependencies in Gradle repository:
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/io.appium%3Ajava-client
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
group 'com.my.group'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/'
        }
    }
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.11.0'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:6.1.0' // /compile 'io.appium:java-client:6.0.0-BETA5'
    //compile 'io.appium:java-client:6.0.0-BETA5' // compile 'io.appium:java-client:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy, dependsOn: build) {
    String dst = "$rootDir/jar"
    description "Copy library JAR dependencies to $dst"
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$dst"
}

task copyToOut(type: Copy, dependsOn: build) {
    String dst = "$rootDir/out"
    description "Copy library JAR output to $dst"
    from jar
    into "$dst"
}

task deploy {
   dependsOn clean
   dependsOn build
   dependsOn copyToLib
   dependsOn copyToOut
}

task buildJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
  exclude 'srcOld/**'
  classpath += sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
  source += sourceSets.main.allJava
}
```

**edit**

When Gradle deletes the modules, it also delete `gradle.build` and the gradle wrapper. I've already created a brand new project with the default Java template, and copied and pasted my code into it, but the problem persists.

Comment: Could you paste your gradle buildscript and a screenshot of File->project structure->Modules. It seems like you are trying to configure your modules using intellij but in reality that dosen't work as intellij follows the projects configured using gradles build script

Comment: @th3sp33dst3r So you think in the build script I might have not defined the modules, and itellij removes modules automatically because auto import is enabled?

Comment: no, actually gradle leaves any already existing modules defined using intellij untouched and you could also create other intellij defined modules when you're using gradle. The above message crops up when you remove an already defined sub-project(as gradle calls it) in your `settings.gradle` script by removing it fom `includes`. Did you or anyone else recently edit the settings.gradle file in the root project?

Comment: So did this happen after you made the changes i suggested or did you make any changes? Is your issue resolved? because from the edit you made, You get the `import project...` option when you make changes to any of the `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle` files and also the problem of your modules getting deleted seems to be solved.

Comment: @th3sp33dst3r the modules are still deleted if I enable auto import which is why I imported the build Gradle file as a new project and left auto import unchecked, so now IDE asks me I would like to enable auto import, but no behaviour has changed, this is just a work around. Sorry, but I can't tell which changes you reccomended. I do not believe anyone has touched the build Gradle file, though I could double check in git history. What changes did you reccomend?

Comment: Oh I see you mean to add an include statement, no I have not tried this yet, do you think it will solve the issue? I should try then.

Comment: What is root project directory ? An absolute path ? I guess it must be relative, makes sense. And then the last directory is the project modules directory right ? So I should try adding two include statementals? Ok I will try that . I can make another git branch and do it easily.

Comment: yeah youre right

Answer (score 0):

In case of a Gradle projects IDE configures the project structure including the modules that are included in project according your the build.gradle script. E.g. if you have **Create separate module per source set** option enabled in IDE Gradle settings IDE creates separate module for each Grale source set. It does it when [re-importing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_refresh_project) build.gradle file. If you have auto-import enabled in IDE Gradle configuration it does it automatically.

Comment: So you think in the build script I might have not defined the modules, and itellij removes modules automatically because auto import is enabled?

Comment: You may open/check out the project with the IDE configuration (including modules) already existed and this configuration does not correspond to what configuration IDE applies when importing it from build.gradle file.

Comment: Thank you, I have included my `build.gradle` file in an edit to my post. I do not see any code corresponding to the modules which are being removed by IDE, so I assume that the modules have been deleted from the `build.gradle` file, and I am not sure how to add them back, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited information, I'll give you an ad-hoc fix, just add `-----test` as a sub-project directory to your root projects `settings.gradle` using

`include 'root-proj-dir:dir1:dir2:...:----test'`

where the directory structure is

```
root-proj-dir
|
|
----dir1
|   |
|   |
|   ----dir2
|       |
|       |
|       ....----test
----settings.gradle
|
----build.gradle
```

For more info on dealing with multi-module (or multi-project in Gradle terminology ) builds [refer this link](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/)